# How to disregard -inf and move to next iteration in for loop

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, numpy, continue

Hello I'm hoping for some help I'm quite new to python and I wanted some advice on ways I can set up a condition so that if -inf is encounter in my data then the programme will loop to the next iteration

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from scipy.signal import butter, filtfilt
from scipy import interpolate
Ic = 400
lower_Ig = 720 #the lower limit of the generator current Ig
Upper_Ig = 1040 #Upper limit
Ix=range(-60,61,1)
for j in range(40, 80, 10):
    Var=(40000* j)/ 10000
    #print Var
    for c in range(lower_Ig, Upper_Ig+1, 40):
        #print c
        Names =['Vg','V3', 'V4']
        Data = pd.read_csv('/Documents/JTL_'+str(Var)+'/Ig='+str(c)+'/Grey_Zone.csv', names=Names)
        Vg = Data['Vg']
        V3 = Data['V3']
        V4 = Data ['V4']
        Prf = V4 / Vg
        #print Prf
        C = 0.802
        freq = 100
        b, a = butter(2, (5/C)/(freq/2), btype = 'low')
        yg = filtfilt(b, a, Vg)  # filter with phase shift correction
        y4 = filtfilt(b, a, V4)  # filter with phase shift correction
        SW = y4 / yg
        if SW == np.nan: #I need a condition here that if -inf is encountered then the programme should loop to next c value in for loop 
            continue 
            f = interp1d( SW, Ix )
            print f(0.25), f(0.5), f(0.75)
            print f(0.75)-f(0.25)
```

I have attempted using different numpy functions but I always get the same error

```
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I dont think I can use `any()` or `all()` since that will just include all the data and I want to ignore -inf. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: what line gives you that error?

Comment: @rpattiso `if SW == np.nan` causes the error

Comment: Why will using `any` or `all` include all the data? And what would it include them in?

Comment: @rpattiso from my understanding from the documents `all` returns the whole array with out evaluating anything in the array and does not distinguish between -inf or a value and the same is true for any, Unless I have completely miss understood that? What I want is to check for any NaN values and once and NaN value is encountered the file is disregarded and the loop moves on to the next iteration i.e. the next file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have `SW` in one iteration of the loop looking like this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> SW = [np.inf, -np.inf, np.nan, 0, 1]
>>> np.isfinite(SW)
[False, False, False, True, True]
>>> all(np.isfinite(SW))
False   # since one or more in the list is False
```

If you want to skip any `SW` that has `nan, inf, -inf` you can use

```
if not all(np.isfinite(SW)):
    continue
```

if `nan` is not a problem and only `-inf` is then you can use

```
if any(np.isneginf(SW)):
   continue
```

Which will skip the iteration if any element of `SW` is `-inf`

Note that you cannot compare for equality using `==` with `np.nan`

```
>>> x = np.nan
>>> x == np.nan
False
```

instead you use `isnan`

```
>>> np.isnan(x)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `filter` out the unwanted elements (e.g. `newlist=filter(lambda n: not numpy.isneginf(n), list_of_numbers)`) or just convert to a list of proper numbers using `numpy.nan_to_num(...)`.

Comment: Wouldn't this just end up including the -inf in the loop instead of ignoring them? I also I tried the `numpy.nan_to_num(...)` as `SW = numpy.nan_to_num(SW)` but when I enter the condition `if SW > -1:` I get the same error as above `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you; where (as: in which line?) does that occur? If it is in the `if SW==numpy.nan` line, then you should obviously consider the meaning of the warning; SW is an array, and comparing an array to a value will yield an array of truth values, not a single one; thus, the warning is absolutely correct, you should specify whether you want to check for *any* NaN or for *all* values of SW being NaN.

Comment: This is probably down to my lack of knowledge regarding python arrays. What I want is to check for any NaN values and once and NaN value is encountered the file is disregarded and the loop moves on to the next iteration i.e. the next file.

Comment: well, then test for "not any"